# SQL Query to get User Defined Fields joined into one row

Tags: sql, join, entity-attribute-value

Dearest genius folk,

I have a **vendor** table, and a **UDF** (User Defined Functions) table.  I need to query some data from the **vendor** table as well as data from the **UDF** table.  Now, there will be more than one UDF result per vendor_id.  (vendor_id and ud_join are the links between tables).

Vendor Table

```
| vendor_id  |  vendor_name  |  vendor_address  |  vendor_status |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    1234    |  ABC Company  |  123 Fourth St.  |    Active      |
```

UDF Table

```
|  udjoin  |  udtype  |  udindex  |  udvalue  |
-----------------------------------------------
|   1234   |   VN     |    36     |  Data36   |
-----------------------------------------------
|   1234   |   VN     |    53     |  Data53   |
-----------------------------------------------
|   1234   |   VN     |    67     |  Data67   |
```

I want to query the vendor_id of "1234", with a returned result of:

```
| vendor_id  |  vendor_name  |  vendor_address  |  vendor_status |  udf_36  |  udf_53  |  udf_67  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1234    |  ABC Company  |  123 Fourth St.  |     Active     |  Data36  |  Data53  |  Data67  |
```

Hopefully this can be done with a basic query.
Thank you in advance for all of your assistance.

Comment: Do you mean there are exactly 3 different udindex values (36, 53 and 67), or may other values show up?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, show the query that joins the table and the UDF. And, please, update the tags to show which server (SQL Server, My SQL, ???) are you using. It totally depends in the server how you can achieve it (if at all possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to investigate the PIVOT operation; its availability and precise semantics depends upon the RDBMS you are using.  Here are a few useful links to get you started:

- SQL Server: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
- Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

If you search the stackoverflow archives for "SQL Pivot" you will find many related questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to transpose the data, Use PIVOT feature in SQL. Please refer

https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/

Hope this will help